# Show image if a post is featured

Tags: sticky-post, featured-post

I know that posts that are sticky show on top but I want to add an image to show that is featured is there any code I could use

Comment: What have you coded so far? Please post the code you have tried as an EDIT to your question.

Comment: I don't have a code I'm wondering if there is one

Comment: You need to provide the code you have tried rather than expect volunteers to do your work for you for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the conditional tag, [`is_sticky()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_sticky) to check whether or not a specific post is a sticky post or not.

You can try the following **inside** your loop

```
if( is_sticky() ) {

    //Display your desired image

}
```